I can't make my shell script detect spaces and hyphens in file names
I'm a hobbyist media collector and I recently started a project of mine, being a self-hosted media server with my owned media. I've been doing everything manually for a while but started getting into shell scripting for it to automate a lot of typing. In my script for compressing seasons of series I can't get the script to detect spaces and hyphens on the file name.
There's my script:

echo "Warning! Please ensure before running this script 
    that the files you'd like to convert are in the following format: 
    'series_name - SXXEYY' and mind that by running this script 
    you're aware that the uncompressed files are goint to be 
    automatically deleted. If you change your mind press 'Ctrl + C' 
    to cancel or press [ENTER] to continue:"
read
echo "Enter destination of the input folder:"
read input
echo "Enter series name(how it's written inside the folder):"
read series_name
echo "Enter season number:"
read season_no
echo "Enter number of episodes in the season:"
read ep_no
echo "Enter destination of the output folder:"
read output

for i in $(seq -f "%02g" 1 $ep_no); do
    input_file="$input/"$series_name - S${season_no}E${i}.mkv""
    output_file="$output/"$series_name - S${season_no}E${i}.mkv""
    ffmpeg -i "$input_file" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a copy -c:s copy -map 0 "$output_file"
done
rm -rf "$input"
clear
echo "Done :)"

and here's how I save my files:
nesco@nesker:~/uncompressed/Rome$ ls
'Rome - S01E01.mkv'  'Rome - S01E02.mkv'

I'm currently extracting the raw files again because last time I ran the script it did not detect and erased the folder

Try to replace input_file="$input/"$series_name - S${season_no}E${i}.mkv"" with input_file="$input/$series_name - S${season_no}E${i}.mkv". Same for the output.

ShellCheck is your friend.

A good beginner question and using for i in $(seq -f "%02g" 1 $ep_no)? Good show! You're getting the idea about shell scripting! BUT ... (-;, Verbal descriptions of problems are often/usually ambiguous. Give us some sample data to work with, the expected output, your current code, output, and error messages formatted using the {} tool on the Edit Menu. You can make it really easy for readers and include "make test data steps" like mkdir testData ; cd testData ; touch file1 'file2 - with spaces' to show your issues. Good luck.

A couple stlyistic things. Using clear can make it more difficult to see the evidence of what went wrong. After you've used your script for 2 yrs, maybe you can uncomment it (-; Pretty much anytime you see "" in your code (2 dbl-quotes), there is likely a better way (in this case as shown in RP's comment above). And, as you learned the hard way, using rm -rm something can be very painful. Again, for the first 2 years of shell development, just echo rm -rf something and then after confirming the sanity, copy/paste to execute that command (there are other ways to verify, but got to go).

Why are you bothering asking for the season number and number of episodes? Do you typically only want to compress some of the shows before deleting all of them? Why not just process all the files in the "input" directory to the "output" directory:
#!/bin/bash
echo "Warning! Please ensure before running this script
    that the files you'd like to convert are in the following format:
    'series_name - SXXEYY' and mind that by running this script
    you're aware that the uncompressed files are going to be
    automatically deleted. If you change your mind press 'Ctrl + C'
    to cancel or press [ENTER] to continue:"
read
read -p "Enter destination of the input folder: " input
read -p "Enter destination of the output folder: " output

if [ ! -d "$input" ]; then
    echo "Error: $input is not a directory."
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d "$output" ]; then
    echo "Error: $output is not a directory."
    exit 1
fi

set -e # force the shell to exit if commands fail.
for input_file in "${input}"/*; do
    output_file="$output"/$(basename "$input_file")
    ffmpeg -i "$input_file" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a copy -c:s copy -map 0 "$output_file"
done
rm -rf "$input"
# clear  # why do this?
echo "Done :)"

Notice that I put in some error checking, pretty important to do, since you are deleting data.
